# Namespace 'NodeJS' has no exported member 'Timeout'

Tags: node.js, angular

When i run code i get this error

```
ERROR in node_modules/@wry/context/lib/context.d.ts(6,84): error
TS2694: Namespace 'NodeJS' has no exported member 'Timeout'.
```

I am using angular7

Comment: delete `node_modules` and run `npm install` command

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Same here. It happened to be an issue with the version of the "@types/node"-dependency that was defined in my devDependencies. Upgrading it to the latest version (12.0.2) fixed it for me.

`npm i @types/node`

Comment: Thanks ! Think to update update your package.json `"@types/node": "^12.0.2"`

Comment: Thanks updating helped

Answer (score 2):

if you're using yarn, just run

```
yarn add --dev @types/node
```

to fix your package.json

Answer (score 0):

If you have this problem with Jest, add following line into your jest.d.ts file:

```
/// <reference types="@types/node/timers"/>
```